# simulating scrolling behavior in HTML5 canvas with touch events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch, touch-event

I have an animation in HTML5 Canvas that simulates scrolling when the user clicks and drags. It moves vertically when the screen is vertical and horizontally when horizontal.

```
this.scroll = function(e) {
    // scroll behavior for canvas
    // feed x movements into horizontal (true) comic, y movments into (false) vertical
    // this number is zero or less, hence added to displacements
    comic.readShift += (comic.orientation ? e.movementX : e.movementY);
    // ... other code here
    comic.drawPanels();
};
```

Listeners hook this up:

```
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", comic.scroll);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", comic.scroll);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", comic.scroll);
    });
```

[This works](http://themoonfellonme.com/2020/01-autumn-home/), as far as I can tell, on desktop browsers. But now I'm trying to get it to work on mobile. With no equivalent for `movement[X|Y]` for touch events, I tried this for the scroll behavior...

```
this.drag = function(e) {
    // scroll behavior on touch screen
    var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    var movementX = comic.touchstart.screenX - touch.screenX;
    var movementY = comic.touchstart.screenY - touch.screenY;
    // decrement in this case
    comic.readShift -= (comic.orientation ? movementX : movementY);
    // ... other code here
    comic.drawPanels();
};
```

`comic.touchstart` gets recorded by the `touchstart` listener:

```
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        comic.touchstart = e.changedTouches[0];
        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", comic.drag);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", comic.drag);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(e) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", comic.drag);
    });
```

Which isn't very good. It'll function if the user swipes really slowly, but normal swiping causes weird acceleration of the scrolling effect and finally borks the page. Do `Touch` events have `movementX` and `movementY` equivalents? If not, what's the right way to set this up?